# Android add view programmatically around another view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

```
<LinearLayout>
   TextView
   TextView
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to programmatically add a custom view around the LinearLayout so the resultant should be

```
<CustomView>
    <LinearLayout>
       TextView
       TextView
    </LinearLayout>
</CustomView>
```

Is this is even possible.

addView doesn't give me too many options

Comment: is your initial view inside a separate file or is part of a bigger layout hierarchy?

Comment: Its part of the bigger layout hierarchy in the same file

Comment: Not sure if it is possible but the following should probably work: 1 - get the parent of the view, 2 - remove the view, 3 - add new parent as a child to the first parent, 4 - add view back to the new parent

Comment: ^ was typing the same stuff...this guy beat me to it :|